# How to make Ant reading lines of a file into a comma separated property?

Tags: ant

I am wondering which is the easiest way to read the contents of a file into a comma-delimited property suitable as an argument for the `files` attribute of `filelist`. I have two solutions but I am not satisfied with either of them and I would like to ask if anybody knows a better (shorter) way.

This works only with newer Ants and it does not seem to be trustworthy, because each line of the input file gets prefixed with the `basedir`, which makes it necessary to call `flattenmapper` to remove the directory again.

```
<pathconvert property="files2" pathsep=",">
  <resources>
    <resourcelist>
      <file file="IMPORT"/>
    </resourcelist>
  </resources>
  <flattenmapper/>
</pathconvert>
```

Does anybody know how to avoid `flattenmapper` in this example? I tried to specify the `basedir` attribute in `file` but it has no effect.

Another approach is `loadfile` with a `filterchain`:

```
<loadfile property="files1" srcFile="IMPORT">
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <replaceregex pattern="$" replace=","/>
    </tokenfilter>
    <striplinebreaks/>
    <tokenfilter>
      <replaceregex pattern=",$" replace=""/>
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</loadfile>
```

This seems better to me, because it works also with older Ants, but it is much more to type.

Is there an shorter way?

Comment: I would think you pretty much nailed it... May I ask why is using the flattenmapper bothersome to you in the first example ?

Comment: @PatriceM. It makes it impossible to use relative directory names in the file list. They would not survive the `flattenmapper`, because `flattenmapper` removes all directories.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe the <mappedresources> construct can help (see a more detailed answer below)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to flattenmapper when using relative paths in your import file is to use <mappedresources> as in:

```
<pathconvert property="files2" pathsep=",">
  <resources>
   <mappedresources>
    <resourcelist>
      <file file="IMPORT"/>
    </resourcelist>
    <globmapper from="*" to="${my.base.dir}/*"/>
   </mappedresources>
  </resources>
  <flattenmapper/>
</pathconvert>
```